# get rows from two tables using join and sub query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table of `Persons`

> Person_ID , Person_Name

another table of `Person_Vehicle_Relation`

> PV_ID , Person_ID , Vehicle_ID, Role

I want to build a query in which I can get the list of

> PV_ID , Person_Name

`where Vehicle_ID= 3 and Role = 'Driver'`.

I have tried join in following way but it is not working. How can I get my desired data?

```
Select Persons.Person_Name , Person_Vehicle_Relation.PV_ID
 from Persons  
 inner join Person_Vehicle_relations on Persons.Person_ID = (select Person_ID from Person_Vehicle_relations where Vehicle_ID = 3 and Role= 'driver')
```

and error was

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>       Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: The error message couldn't be more clear.  Your subquery returns more than one row.  = can only compare a value.  Replace with `IN` if you need multiple rows comparison.

Comment: Also tag properly.  It's either MySQL or SQL Server, can't be both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need a subquery/inline view? a simple where should work.

```
SELECT P.Person_Name , PVR.PV_ID
FROM Persons P
INNER join Person_Vehicle_relations  PVR
   on P.Person_ID = PRV.Person_ID
WHERE PVR.Vehicle_ID = 3 
  and PVR.Role= 'driver'
```

The reason why you had an error is because the subquery returned multiple persons and a single person_ID  from person's can't match multiple persons from PVR.

You could switch it to "IN" instead of "=" and it should work as well; but a join and a where clause seemed the simplest to maintain and run.

One normally joins on the PK/FK relationship then applies limits in the where or in a having.  I generally only use subquery/inline views instead of a straight join when I need aggregation done and a M-M relationship would artificially inflate the aggregation.  I may use subqueries also in cross applies or in exists when I don't need data from the second table.  In this case you needed data from both tables so a join seemed the best.